# When exactly does a called function end?

Tags: c++, function, return-value

From a textbook I was reading, it is said that for functions with a return value, the return value is used to initialize a temporary at the call site.

What I want to know is does that happen *before* or *after* the called function exits? In other words, if I have a variable(say, an `int`) defined inside the called function, will it get destroy before or after the temporary is initialized?

Comment: The return value is set before local variables go out of the scope. You could not do `int localVar = 5; return localVar;` otherwise.

Comment: "If i have a variable defined inside a function, will it get destroyed **before** or after the temporary is initialized?" Think about that question....

Comment: @Melebius yes, I figured as much. The return value must be set before the function terminates. What I am confused is that 'temporary initializing' part. Is the return value used to initialize a temporary or is setting the return value equilvalent to creating a temporary?

Comment: @ZylonD.Lite Could you figure out an example where it would make a difference? I find those two options pretty same.

Comment: @Melebius honestly speaking, I can't think of any. Because no matter what order they are done in, I guess they would be consecutively executed. I am just learning the language and sometime I tend to overthink. This question was purely academic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Before

For functions returning by value, the temporary at the call site will be initialized *before* the scope of the function exits. Otherwise, any return value would be destroyed before it could be passed to the call site.

Answer (score 3):

This is the technical view. This might not be interesting to language-lawyers, but for other people, it might me instructive.

---

A function ends precisely with the branch instruction that transfers control back to the caller. Before this point, the callee has full control, after this point, the caller has full control over what the CPU does. Generally, there is precisely one CPU instruction that is used for this control transfer. On X86-64, that's the `ret` instruction, PowerPC used `blr`, other CPUs have other names for the same thing. The name does not matter, though.

Anything, that's within the responsibility of the function itself must happen before this instruction, anything that's none of the callee's business happens somewhere else.

As the caller does not know which variables a function creates, it cannot be the callers responsibility to destruct them. More generally, the callee has to release any stack space that it allocated for its own purposes. As such, the callee must perform such cleanup itself before exiting by issuing the `ret` instruction. This means, that any local variables must vanish before the function exits.

Things are a bit more complicated when it comes to returning a result from a function: This requires both caller and callee to collaborate. The details differ between the different calling conventions, but there are generally two cases:

1. The return value is passed in a register.
   In this case, the callee will load the return value into a well-known register, and the caller will use that same register to access the return value.
2. The return value is passed on the stack.
   In this case, the callee will place the data that is to be returned at a defined position within the callers stack frame, and the caller will examine that same memory region for the functions result after the call has returned.

TL;DR: If something is a functions responsibility, it must happen before the function returns (= executes the `ret` instruction). Freeing stack space and returning data to the caller are such responsibilities.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you.

Comment: @ZylonD.Lite So why don’t you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer?

Comment: @Melebius because cmaster's answer came after I have accepted Snps' answer. And his answer, while shorter, also responds to what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

The Function ends after a return statement 
the variables that are declared in that scope will go out of scope and you will not be able to use that unless the variable is declared as static